# If $p(x)$ is a function such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^m} p(x) dx$ then can I say it is the density of a probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}^m$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

(I am aware this is a bit imprecise. I will make it more precise with time)

Suppose $\mu$ is a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^m$ and that $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure on the same space. I have found a function $p(x)\geq 0$ such that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^m} p(x) \lambda(x) = 1.
$$
Can I say that $p(x)$ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\mu$ with respect to $\lambda$?

> I am aware of the definition of Randon-Nikodym derivative. One requires $\mu\ll \lambda$ and then the RN derivative is a measurable function $f$ such that $\mu(A) = \int f(x) \lambda (x)$ for every measurable set $A$. However this is somehow the reverse of that statement.

Comment: This is not clear.  Your defining relation for $p(x)$ doesn't even mention $\mu$.  And, of course, just having a function that integrates to $1$ does not a probability density make (non-negativity matters).

Comment: @lulu My bad, I know for a fact that $p(x) \geq 0$ for every $x$. This is the context: I don't know whether $\mu \ll \lambda$, however I managed to construct a function such that $\int p(x) dx = 1$ and $p(x)\geq 0$ and I would like to **define** the density of $\mu$ with respect to $\lambda$ as $p(x)$

Comment: Again, your relation doesn't even mention $\mu$ so there's nothing to connect $p$ to $\mu$.

Comment: Of course you can *define* $\mu(A)=\int_A p(x)$, where $A$ is some element of whatever $\sigma$ algebra you had in mind. (I'm trusting that $p$ is suitably integrable here). Is that what you meant to say?  The way you wrote it, I thought $\mu$ was defined a priori.